# If $\mathbb P(A_r\cap A_s)=p$ and $\mathbb P(A_r\cap A_s\cap A_t)=q$, express $q$ in terms of $p$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

> Let $A_r$, ($1\le r\le n$) be events such that, $\mathbb P(A_r\cap A_s)=p$ and $\mathbb P(A_r\cap A_s\cap A_t)=q$, ($r<s<t$). If the probability of at least two occurring is $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and it is certain that no more than 3 occur,  express $q$ in terms of $p$

at least 2 of the events occur with probability $\dfrac{1}{2}$ means

$\dfrac{1}{2}=\mathbb P(\bigcup\limits_{r<s}(A_r\cap A_s))=\sum\limits_{r<s}\mathbb P(A_r\cap A_s)-\sum\limits_{r<s<t}\mathbb P(A_r\cap A_s\cap A_t)=\binom{n}{2}p-\binom{n}{3}q$

Hence $3p-\dfrac{3}{n(n-1)}=q$

Does this look correct ?

Comment: Try it with $n=3$,

Comment: @Bilou06 for n=3 it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $i<j$ let $L_{ij}=A_i\cap A_j \cap \bigcap_{k\not\in\lbrace i,j \rbrace} \overline{A_k}$. By hypothesis, 
$A_i\cap A_j$ can be decomposed as the following disjoint union :

$$
A_i\cap A_j=L_{ij} \cup \bigcup_{k\not\in\lbrace i,j \rbrace} A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k
$$

Taking probabilities on each side, we deduce

$$
p=P(L_{ij})+(n-2)q,P(L_{ij})=p-(n-2)q
$$

Let $Z$ be the event : “at least two of the $A_i$ occur.” By hypothesis,
$Z$ is the disjoint union of all the $L_{ij}$ and the $A_u\cap A_v \cap A_w$, so

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
P(Z) &=& \sum_{i < j} P(L_{ij})+\sum_{u < v < w} P(A_u\cap A_v \cap A_w) \\
&=& \binom{n}{2}(p-(n-2)q)+\binom{n}{3}q \\
&=& \frac{n(n-1)}{2}p-\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3}q
\end{array}
$$

It follows that

$$
q=\frac{3p}{2(n-2)}-\frac{3}{2n(n-1)(n-2)}
$$

Comment: How did you get $(n-2)$ (line 6: $p=P(L_{ij})+(n-2)q...$)

Comment: @O.B.D.A. because there are $n-2$ possible values for $k$, outside of $\lbrace i,j \rbrace$